# No microphone input. Ubuntu 14.04, Asus x550ln

Tags: sound, microphone

I can't use my microphone after installing ubuntu 14.04. I have made a little research and using alsamixer and pavucontrol to chance microphone configurations had no results at all.

After installing ubuntu audio development team driver I could hear some static and very low sound.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I'm a new linux user and would appreciate some detailed help.

Comment: I manage to get some sound, but seems to be similar to what you got through the developer drive. A lot of white noise and low voice. If you get any news I appreciate.